# PHP doesn't post form values after migrating login page

Tags: php

I've decided to change the design on our login page, however there is a issue.
In the new login page nothing pass after I press the login button however on the old page it still works as before.
**Old page:**

```
<?php
    require_once('./files/functions.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="Social Panel">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
        <title><?php echo($WebsiteName); ?> | Sign In</title>
        <link href="bs3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body class="login-body">
        <div class="container">
            <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">sign in now</h2>
                <div class="login-wrap">
                    <div class="user-login-info">
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" autofocus required>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                        <span class="pull-right">
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"> Forgot Password?</a>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block">
                    <div class="registration">
                        Don't have an account yet?
                        <a class="" href="registration.php">Create an account</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
                    if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) &&
                    is_string($_POST['email']) && is_string($_POST['password']) &&
                    !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
                        $email = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
                        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

                        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserEmail = :UserEmail');
                        $stmt->bindParam(':UserEmail', $email);
                        $stmt->execute();

                        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserEmail = :UserEmail AND UserPassword = :UserPassword');
                            $stmt->execute(array(':UserEmail' => $email, ':UserPassword' => $password));

                            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                                $row = $stmt->fetch();
                                $UserLevel = $row['UserLevel'];

                                if($UserLevel == 'banned') {
                                    $display->ReturnError('Your account has been suspended.');
                                    return false;
                                }
                                $UserID = $row['UserID'];
                                $time = time();
                                $IPAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

                                $_SESSION['auth'] = $UserID;

                                $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO logs (LogUserID, LogDate, LogIPAddress) VALUES (:LogUserID, :LogDate, :LogIPAddress)');
                                $stmt->execute(array(':LogUserID' => $UserID, ':LogDate' => $time, ':LogIPAddress' => $IPAddress));

                                $display->ReturnSuccess('You was successfully logged in.');
                                $settings->forceRedirect('index.php', 2);
                            } else {
                                $display->ReturnError('Invalid user credentials.');
                            }
                        } else {
                            $display->ReturnError('User with these credentials does not exists.');
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="bs3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/sm-requests.js"></script>

        <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <form method="POST">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Forgot Password ?</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Enter your user name below.</p>
                            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="User Name" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" autocomplete="off" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Enter your e-mail address below.</p>
                            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" autocomplete="off" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                            <button id="reset" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Reset</button>
                            <hr>
                            <div id="result"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**New Page:**

```
<?php
    require_once('./files/functions.php');
?>
<html lang="en">

<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>log in</title>

        <!-- Vendors -->

        <!-- Animate CSS -->
        <link href="vendors/bower_components/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Material Design Icons -->
        <link href="vendors/bower_components/material-design-iconic-font/dist/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Site CSS -->
        <link href="css/app-1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

    <body>
        <div class="login">
            <form action="" >
            <!-- Login -->
            <div class="login__block toggled" id="l-login">
                <div class="login__block__header">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-circle"></i>
                    Hi there! Please Sign in

                    <div class="actions login__block__actions">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="zmdi zmdi-more-vert"></i></a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                <li><a data-block="#l-register" href="#">Create an account</a></li>
                                <li><a data-block="#l-forget-password" href="#">Forgot password?</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="login__block__body">
                <form action="" >
                    <div class="form-group form-group--float form-group--centered form-group--centered">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group form-group--float form-group--centered form-group--centered">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                    </div>
                    <button name="login" class="btn btn--light btn--icon m-t-15"><i class="zmdi zmdi-long-arrow-right"></i></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
                    if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) &&
                    is_string($_POST['email']) && is_string($_POST['password']) &&
                    !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
                        $email = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
                        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

                        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserEmail = :UserEmail');
                        $stmt->bindParam(':UserEmail', $email);
                        $stmt->execute();

                        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserEmail = :UserEmail AND UserPassword = :UserPassword');
                            $stmt->execute(array(':UserEmail' => $email, ':UserPassword' => $password));

                            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                                $row = $stmt->fetch();
                                $UserLevel = $row['UserLevel'];

                                if($UserLevel == 'banned') {
                                    $display->ReturnError('Your account has been suspended.');
                                    return false;
                                }
                                $UserID = $row['UserID'];
                                $time = time();
                                $IPAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

                                $_SESSION['auth'] = $UserID;

                                $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO logs (LogUserID, LogDate, LogIPAddress) VALUES (:LogUserID, :LogDate, :LogIPAddress)');
                                $stmt->execute(array(':LogUserID' => $UserID, ':LogDate' => $time, ':LogIPAddress' => $IPAddress));

                                $display->ReturnSuccess('You was successfully logged in.');
                                $settings->forceRedirect('index.php', 2);
                            } else {
                                $display->ReturnError('Invalid user credentials.');
                            }
                        } else {
                            $display->ReturnError('User with these credentials does not exists.');
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Register -->
            <div class="login__block" id="l-register">
                <div class="login__block__header palette-Blue bg">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-circle"></i>
                    Create an account

                    <div class="actions login__block__actions">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="zmdi zmdi-more-vert"></i></a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                <li><a data-block="#l-login" href="#">Already have an account?</a></li>
                                <li><a data-block="#l-forget-password" href="#">Forgot password?</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="login__block__body">
                    <div class="form-group form-group--float form-group--centered">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group form-group--float form-group--centered">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group form-group--float form-group--centered">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-centered">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="">
                                <i class="input-helper"></i>
                                Accept the license agreement
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn--light btn--icon m-t-15"><i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Forgot Password -->
            <div class="login__block" id="l-forget-password">
                <div class="login__block__header palette-Purple bg">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-circle"></i>
                    Forgot Password?

                    <div class="actions login__block__actions">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="zmdi zmdi-more-vert"></i></a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                <li><a data-block="#l-login" href="#">Already have an account?</a></li>
                                <li><a data-block="#l-register" href="#">Create an account</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="login__block__body">
                    <p class="m-t-30">Lorem ipsum dolor fringilla enim feugiat commodo sed ac lacus.</p>

                    <div class="form-group form-group--float form-group--centered">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn--light btn--icon m-t-15"><i class="zmdi zmdi-check"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Older IE Warning -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <div class="ie-warning">
                <h1>Warning!!</h1>
                <p>You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer, please upgrade <br/>to any of the following web browsers to access this website.</p>
                <div class="ie-warning__container">
                    <ul class="ie-warning__download">
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/">
                                <img src="img/browsers/chrome.png" alt="">
                                <div>Chrome</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/">
                                <img src="img/browsers/firefox.png" alt="">
                                <div>Firefox</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.opera.com">
                                <img src="img/browsers/opera.png" alt="">
                                <div>Opera</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.apple.com/safari/">
                                <img src="img/browsers/safari.png" alt="">
                                <div>Safari</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie">
                                <img src="img/browsers/ie.png" alt="">
                                <div>IE (New)</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p>Sorry for the inconvenience!</p>
            </div>
        <![endif]-->


        <!-- Javascript Libraries -->

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="vendors/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="vendors/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Placeholder for IE9 -->
        <!--[if IE 9 ]>
            <script src="vendors/bower_components/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Site Functions & Actions -->
        <script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your using **`<form>`** tags without no **action** attribute (takes the url link which will handle the form) and **method** attributes(set this to POST, that is **`method="POST"`**). look through your code and correct this.

Each time you use and input field and what to get the data which the user inputted, enclosed it inside a form tags like this:

```
<form action="form processor url here" method="POST"> 
   <!--input fields here or fields that you want the to submit data-->

   <input type=text name=username >
   <button name=login value=login >
</form>
```

Comment: If I recall properly, a form with `action=""` is perfectly valid and the form will simply submit to the same URL as the page. However, yes, I think you are right about him needing to set the method.

Comment: @Sol E-pAt the problem is that I don't have any submisson url. I never used one on my old login page.